# Trigger submit button only onetime in jquery(via code not by mouseclick or key press)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how to trigger submit button only once using jquery

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id=submit click='click'>
</form>

<script>
$("#submit").trigger('click',function());
</script>
```

it went into infinite loops..

please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use the unbind to remove the click event.when you call the click function add this. 
`$( "#submit" ).unbind( "submit" );`

Comment: Use `.submit();`. [Link](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: Your code does just that if you remove anything name or id="submit" - it runs only once when the page is loaded. If you want it to never run again, remove it from the dom and set a cookie

Comment: Read about event propagation and default action.

Comment: NEVER call anything in a form "submit" - it hides the form's submit event handler

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach would be to disable the button after clicking, but if you want the click handler to only execute once, use the `one` method provided by jQuery:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    $("#Submit").one('click',function(event) { alert("Do this once only!")});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You will want to make the input a button rather than type `submit` since you want to manage the event that occurs when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `one()` event handler, also you should put quotes around the id of the input button and not call it submit:

```js
$("#subBut").one('click', function() {
  console.log('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id='subBut'>
</form>

<script>
</script>
```

Also, I don't know why you used `click='click'` attribute. Maybe you meant to use `onclick`. If you just wanted to add a custom attribute I recommend you to make use of the `data-*` atributtes.

Comment: note that the form is not actually submitted in SO's sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind` inside the event.

```js
$("#submit").trigger('click', function(event) {
  /* 
    do something
     ...
  */
  
   $(this).unbind(event); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id='submit' click='click'>
</form>
```

Comment: Got it. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the submit() function to submit forms.

```
$("form")[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Trigger click event on submit button

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" >
</form>

<script>
$("#submit").trigger("click");
</script>
```